# Ajax Calls in BackBone - And rendering the View thereafter

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I do have an accordion kind of UI, where for a user there are several nodes to click and expand. On the click of those Nodes,I need to make an Ajax call to one my server side programs.The idea here is make the call, and listen for success or failure and either case , return  back with the Model Object that my view needs to pick and subsequently  pass to the Underscore template to display the values appropriately.

Haven't written a BackBone Ajax call before, and so was interested knowing from experts there, for a given need what should be my best strategy.

Your answers are much appreciated.

Sharad

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options which are basically equivalent and depend on taste. Using callbacks:

```
myModel.fetch({
  success: function(model, response, options){
    // create and display new view
  },
  error: function(model, response, options){
    // display error
  }
});
```

Or the equivalent using deferreds:

```
myModel.fetch().done(function(){
  // create and display new view
}).fail(function(response){
  // display error
});
```